# Decorator for CBV

Tags: django, django-views

I have this CBV:

```
class GetStuff(View):
    def get(self, request, company_id):
        ...
```

I want to decorate the get function with a custom function which takes the request and company_id arguments and check some permissions.

Any idea on how to achieve this? Most information I've found about decorators focus on FBV.

This is what I have so far:

```
def custom_decorator(func_view):
    def wrapper(request, company_id):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            # do_something()
            return func_view(request, company_id)
        return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decorate the dispatch method

> To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the dispatch() method of the class. [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class GetStuff(View):
     @method_decorator(custom_decorator)
     def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
         return super(GetStuff, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

or

```
@method_decorator(custom_decorator, name='dispatch')
class GetStuff(View):
     def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
         return super(GetStuff, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

you can find other decorating techniques in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class)